# display data from xml file in a table php

Tags: php, xml

I have a Xml file i just want to display that data file into the html table format anyone have the idea to do that below is my Xml Code

```
     <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Contact Number</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("banner.xml");
    foreach ($xml->college->student as $ban) :
    ?>
       <tr>
  <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->ContactNumber; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Address->AddressLine1; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Email; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Picture; ?></td>
</tr>
       <?php     
       endforeach;   
       ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

My xml looks like this: 
<college fullname="xCol">
    <student knumber="000555">
                 <Profile>
                    <Name>testtt</Name>
                    <ContactNumber>061-123-1235</ContactNumber>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine1>testttaxxxx</AddressLine1>
                        <AddressLine2>testttsss</AddressLine2>
                        <City>testttaaaa</City>
                        <County>testttwwww</County>
                    </Address>
                    <Email>testtt@test</Email>
                    <Picture>testtt.jpg</Picture>
                </Profile>
             </student>
             <student knumber="34333">
                 <Profile>
                    <Name>testtt</Name>
                    <ContactNumber>061-123-1235</ContactNumber>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine1>testttaxxxx</AddressLine1>
                        <AddressLine2>testttsss</AddressLine2>
                        <City>testttaaaa</City>
                        <County>testttwwww</County>
                    </Address>
                    <Email>testtt@test</Email>
                    <Picture>testtt.jpg</Picture>
                </Profile>
             </student>
```

I am fairly new to the xml, this is probably very simple but I just cannot understand what I am doing wrong.
The output I get are only the headers:

This is the output I get on my site:
**Name Contact Number   Address Email Photo**

*Edit - got **FIRST** profile to show up but cannot get the second one, any ideas?

Comment: `$ban` and `$banner`. You'd need to replace your `echo $banner->`s with `echo $ban->` (from your foreach)

Comment: @kerbholz did not work, but thanks for noticing

Comment: Another thing from your `foreach()`: there is no `$xml->banner`

Comment: change to `foreach ($xml->student as $ban)` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("banner.xml");
foreach ($xml->student as $ban):
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Name;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->ContactNumber;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Address->AddressLine1;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Email;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Picture;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

There is no `$xml->banner` in your xml file but many `student`, so I changed it to `$xml->student`.

Every `student` has a `Profile`, added this to the table.

`Address` has multiple subitems, I only added `AddressLine1` in this code, might need to modify that.

Answer (score -1):

Edited original code to -

```
 <?php 
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("banner.xml");
        foreach ($xml->college->student as $ban) :
        ?>
           <tr>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->ContactNumber; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Address->AddressLine1; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Email; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ban->Profile->Picture; ?></td>
    </tr>
           <?php     
           endforeach;   
           ?>
```